# Getting data from json using jq when key is numerical string

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am new to jq and facing an issue while parsing my json

I have a json stored in a variable like this

```
temp='{ "1": { "my_name": "one" }, "2": { "my_name": "two" } }'
```

Now I need to get the value of my_name for both other entries

I have tried something like this

```
echo $temp | jq '.1' //out put 0.1
I was assuming to get { "my_name": "one" }
```

And similarly to get my_name value I did

```
echo $temp | jq '.1.my_name' // Its output is giving me error
```

Can any one please help to identify what is wrong with my syntax and how can I correct it.

Comment: please edit your question to include the exact command and error message you are getting. Also, i shell programming, it is a good rule-of-thumb to quote any variable use (except for a very few special cases). `echo "$temp" | ...` may help. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @shellter wrapping it around the quotes is still giving the same result.

Comment: my comment about `echo "$temp"` is meant to be a general bit of advice. I didn't mean to say it would solve your problem. I believe the `1` upvote for my comment is for my request that you edit your question to include exact command you are executing AND exact text of error message you are getting. Good luck.

Answer (score 20):

Just the number gets interpreted as a float.  You need to use it in a context where it is unambiguously a key string.

```
echo "$temp" | jq '.["1"]["my_name"]'
```

and

```
echo "$temp" | jq '.["1"]'
```

to get the containing dict.

With a sufficiently new `jq` (I think >= 1.4) you can also say

```
echo "$temp" | jq '."1".my_name'
```

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you are trying to reference a key that is not a valid identifier, you have to quote it.  See the [manual](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#foofoobar) for more details.

To select the item under the key `1`, you'd do this:

```
."1"
```

For your other question on how to obtain the `my_name` values, you could do this:

```
to_entries | map(.value.my_name)
```