# Looping through a json file using jq

Tags: json, linux, bash, command-line, jq

Related to: 
[Getting data from json using jq when key is numerical string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844295/getting-data-from-json-using-jq-when-key-is-numerical-string) but different as I have the numerical key stored in a variable. See the example below.

File `temp.json`:

```
{
  "bccc26321e360ae5fde94aac81eef7c7270bbfd90de0787d0e5b45be4b21ce53": {
    "size": 189,
    "fee": 0.00000678,
    "modifiedfee": 0.00000678,
    "time": 1535906461,
    "height": 539665
  },
  "43906c7227610cd58a1c95714e4f79cd46e0d98ae3f4214f1b2cf325b628b70e": {
    "size": 256,
    "fee": 0.00008328,
    "modifiedfee": 0.00008328,
    "time": 1535906461,
    "height": 539665
  }
}
```

Attempts to index with a variable:

```
#get second key 43906c7227610cd58a1c95714e4f79cd46e0d98ae3f4214f1b2cf325b628b70e
>txid=$(cat temp.json | jq 'keys' | jq .[1] | tr -d '"')
>cat temp.json | jq .$txid
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.43906c7227610cd58a1c95714e4f79cd46e0d98ae3f4214f1b2cf325b628b70e
jq: 1 compile error

>cat temp.json | jq '.$txid'
q: error: syntax error, unexpected '$' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.$txid 
jq: error: try .["field"] instead of .field for unusually named fields at <top-level>, line 1:
.$txid
jq: 2 compile errors

>cat temp.json | jq '."$txid"'
null
```

The desired output is simply

```
>cat temp.json | jq '."43906c7227610cd58a1c95714e4f79cd46e0d98ae3f4214f1b2cf325b628b70e"'
{
        "size": 256,
        "fee": 0.00008328,
        "modifiedfee": 0.00008328,
        "time": 1535906461,
        "height": 539665
      }
```

Comment: If you want the quotes around the key, why do you delete them via `tr`?
With what you have, I'd expect `".\"$txid\""` to work; if you drop the `tr -d '"'`, `".$txid"` may be enough.

Comment: it solved my problem, thanks

Comment: Have added it as an answer; would appreciate it if you could accept it.

Comment: BTW, better to run `jq ... temp.json` or `jq ... <temp.json` or `<temp.json jq ...` than `cat temp.json | jq ...` -- running `cat` means `jq` has to read from a FIFO from a separate program (`cat`) which has access to the file, instead of giving `jq` access to the input file directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is `."xxx"` as argument, then use `".\"$txid\""`.
If you drop the `tr -d '"'`, `".$txid"` may even be enough.